# Trouble setting up jFlex

Tags: java, jflex

I wanted to use jFlex. Tried to search online tutorials. But all points to the same link. 
I could not successfully set up and use Flex on my machine. 
It would be great if some one could point me to a good tutorial.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: [link](http://jflex.de/manual.html#SECTION00031000000000000000). This is the link i am referring to.

Comment: The latest release is from early 2009. Maybe the documentation is a bit outdated for current environments? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes i think so. But ideally, there should be some way to set it up on current systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set this up recently on my 64 and 32 bit windows 7 systems. Here's what I did:

1. Installed the extracted JFlex under my C:.
2. Went into the bin folder (C:\jflex\bin) and edit the JFlex.bat file in my Notepad++
3. There are two paths that need to be edited "JFLEX_HOME" and "JAVA_HOME".
4. Because of my folder structure, I don't have to change "JFlex_HOME", but depending where you have installed it you may need to point to a different directory.
5. JAVA_HOME - You have to browse your programs directory and find your java jdk installation. My JAVA_HOME variable is as follows: 
   set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20"
6. Save changes and run the jflex.bat program in the cmd pmt and you should be good to go.

I hope this helps.